# Json_encode, reuturns hashes at start

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I'm building an array of arrays and then calling json_encode on it.

when it returns its adding #'s to the front of the json, ie it starts ######{

removing the hashes makes it a valid json object.

controller:

multiple nested arrays are created as such

```
$ingredients = array();

foreach($step->ingredient as $in) {
$ingredient_data = array (
"id" => $in->id,
"name" => $in->name,
"description" => $in->description,
"link" => $in->link,
"image" => $in->image_url
 );

array_push($ingredients,$ingredient_data); 
}
```

view:

```
$this->output->set_header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: There is no reason whatsoever why `json_encode` should add those characters – _your_ mistake must be somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks found it elsewhere that happended to be included when it got called.